# find the tangent to the sphere

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

obtain the equations of tangent to sphere

$$x^2+ y^2+z^2+6x-2z+1 = 0$$

which pass through the line

$$3 (16-x) = 3z=2y+30$$

Now I know if the plane is $$lx +my+n z=p$$

then $$-I/3 +m/2+n/3=0$$

also $(16,-15,0)$ is a point on the plane

I know that there is $2$ answers , but how to proceed

Comment: Tangent *what* ?

Answer (score 1):

The line

$$
3 (16-x) = 3z=2y+30=\lambda
$$

can be rearranged as

$$
L\to\cases{
x = 16-\frac{\lambda}{3}\\
y = -15+\frac{\lambda}{2}\\
z = 0 +\frac{\lambda}{3}
}\ \ \ \Rightarrow p = p_0+\lambda v,\ \ \cases{p = (x,y,z)\\ p_0 = (16,-15,0)\\ \vec v = (-\frac 13,\frac 12, \frac 13)\\ \lambda\in \mathbb{R}}
$$

The sphere

$$
x^2+ y^2+z^2+6x-2z+1 = 0\ \ \ \Rightarrow (x+3)^2+y^2+(z-1)^2=3^2 \Rightarrow \|p-p_1\|^2=r^2,\ \ \cases{p_1 = (-3,0,1)\\ r = 3}
$$

Considering now a plane $\Pi$ to determine as

$$
\Pi\to (p-p_2)\cdot \vec n = 0\ \ \ \cases{p_2=(x_2,y_2,z_2)\\ \vec n = (n_x,n_y,n_z)\\ \|\vec n\| = 1}
$$

we need that $L\in\Pi$ so $(p_0+\lambda\vec v-p_2)\cdot\vec n = 0\Rightarrow \cases{(p_0-p_2)\cdot \vec n=0\\
\vec v\cdot \vec n = 0}$

now if $p_2 = S\cap \Pi$ we need $p_2 = p_1 + r\vec n$ so the conditions to determine $\Pi$ are

$$
\cases{(p_0-p_2)\cdot \vec n=0\\
\vec v\cdot \vec n = 0\\ \|\vec n\| = 1\\ p_2 = p_1 + r\vec n}
$$

or substituting values

$$
\cases{
(16-x_2)n_x-(y_2+15)n_y -z_2 n_z=0\\
-\frac{n_x}{3}+\frac{n_2}{2}+\frac{n_z}{3}=0\\
n_x^2+n_y^2+n_z^2=1\\
x_2-3n_x+3=0\\
y_2-3n_y = 0\\z_2-3n_z-1=0
}
$$

and solving we got two solutions:

$$
\Pi_1\to \cases{\vec n_1 = (-\frac 13,\frac 23,\frac 23)\\ (p_2)_1 = (-4,-2,3)}\\
\Pi_2\to \cases{\vec n_2 = (\frac 23,\frac 23,-\frac 13)\\ (p_2)_2 = (-1,2,0)}
$$

Answer (score 0):

The sphere has for equation $$S \equiv (x+3)^2-9+y^2+(z-1)^2-1+1=(x+3)^2+y^2+(z-1)^2-9=0$$ which means that its center is $C= (-3,0,1)$ and its radius is equal to $r=3$. The line has for equations $$L \equiv \begin{cases}
x+z=16\\
2y-3z=-30
\end{cases}$$ It goes through the point $P_L=(16,-15,0)$ and has $v_L=(-2,3,2)$ as a direction vector.

The general equation of a plane $\mathscr P$ is $a x+by+cz+d=0$ where $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$. $\mathscr P$ is passing through $P_L$ so you must have $16a-15b+d=0$. And $\mathscr P$ contains the direction of the line, so $-2a+3b+2c=0$. Finally as $\mathscr P$ is supposed to be tangent to the sphere, the distance of $\mathscr P$ to $C$ is equal to the radius. Hence $\vert -3a+c+d \vert = 3$.

Therefore, you have to solve following system of equations $$\begin{cases}
a^2+b^2+c^2=1\\
16a-15b+d=0\\
-2a+3b+2c=0\\
\vert -3a+c+d \vert = 3
\end{cases}$$

You'll get two different solutions depending on the sign of $\vert -3a+c+d \vert$.

Comment: so I get 4 equations to solve ..Thats why I thought it is bit lengthy

Comment: The interesting part is to understand how to get the right equations. I agree that solving those is more of a routine.

Answer (score 0):

Let $R(a,b,c)$ be the point of tangency, and let $P(16, -15, 0)$ and $Q(6, 0,10)$ be two points on the line.

Since the center of the sphere is $C(-3, 0, 1)$, a normal vector to the plane is given by $\vec{n}=\langle a+3,b,c-1\rangle$.

Therefore the plane has equation $(a+3)(x-a)+b(y-b)+(c-1)(z-c)=0$, which gives

$\;\;\color{blue}{(a+3)x+by+(c-1)z=-3a+c-1}\;\;\;$ since $a^2+b^2+c^2=-6a+2c-1$.

Substituting the coordinates of $Q$ gives $6(a+3)+10(c-1)=-3a+c-1$,

so $a+c=-1$ and $\color{blue}{a=-c-1}$.

Substituting the coordinates of $P$ gives $16(a+3)-15b=-3a+c-1$,

so $3b+4c=6$ and $\color{blue}{b=2-\frac{4}{3}c}$.

Substituting into $a^2+b^2+c^2+6a-2c+1=0$ gives

$(c+1)^2+(2-\frac{4}{3}c)^2+c^2+6(-c-1)-2c+1=0$,

so $\frac{34}{9}c^2-\frac{34}{3}c=0$ and thus $c^2-3c=c(c-3)=0$.

If $c=0$, $a=-1$ and $b=2$; so the plane has equation $\color{red}{2x+2y-z=2}$.

If $c=3$, $a=-4$ and $b=-2$; so the plane has equation $\color{red}{-x-2y+2z=14}$.